# How do I install IBM DB2 Express-C on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos, db2, osx-lion

I was able to install and use IBM DB2 Express-C 9.5.2. beta in Mac OS X Snow Leopard with no trouble at all. In Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, though, installation using the db2setup script fails with:

> DBI1189E There has been an attempt to use db2setup on an image for a platform that does not match the current platform 'Darwin [x86_64]' on which it is being run.

**How can I work around this to install DB2 Express-C on Lion?**

edit: moved answer to answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the db2setup script does not properly recognize the architecture x86_64 reported by

```
uname -m
```

To make the installation script work, edit the db2setup script and change this:

```
"Darwin")
    case ${OSM?} in
      i*86)
        INSTALLDIR="${PROGDIR?}/db2/macos/install"
        PLATNAME="MacOS" ;;
    esac ;;
"HP-UX")
```

to this:

```
"Darwin")
    case ${OSM?} in
      i*86)
          INSTALLDIR="${PROGDIR?}/db2/macos/install"
          PLATNAME="MacOS" ;;
      x86_64)
          INSTALLDIR="${PROGDIR?}/db2/macos/install"
          PLATNAME="MacOS/x86_64" ;;
    esac ;;
"HP-UX")
```

Now run db2setup. The script should recognize the architecture and proceed with installation as normal.

Comment: Nah, just go into the db2/macos/install directory and run the db2setup tool that is there.  The fix you give is closer to the one IBM should make ;-)

Comment: This doesn't work as of 7/2012

Answer (score 0):

Also note that enabling the root account, see the instructions on: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528?viewlocale=en_US