# How do I get ibm_db for Node.js to work with DB2 in Mac OS X 10.10?

Tags: python, node.js, macos, db2

Currently I'm trying to use the [ibm_db](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db) node.js module to connect my application with DB2 as I did it with Windows (my past workstation's OS). I followed some [guides](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/15) about Mac OS X and ibm_db python module just in case, but it also doesn't work. ibm_db got to install but when I make the first database interaction it throws an error :

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle
Referenced from: /Users/devniel/dev/Pon.de.tu.parte/node_modules/ibm_db/build/Release/odbc_bindings.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _SQLAllocHandle
  Referenced from: /Users/devniel/dev/Pon.de.tu.parte/node_modules/ibm_db/build/Release/odbc_bindings.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I posted an [issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/15) on Github, and they explain me that the reason is the lack of a DS Driver for Mac OS X, so, **Is there a way to get it works** such as the python guys [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072973/how-do-i-get-ibm-db-or-pydb2-python-modules-to-work-with-db2-in-mac-os-x-10-7-li)  ? (I will try it tomorrow).

Comment: Do you have the DB2 Client for Mac OS X installed?  (It's definitely not supported (yet) on Yosemite, although it may function)

Comment: Thanks Ian. Where I could download the DB2 client ? Currently I have installed db2 express and I access this trough the terminal or SQuirreL, but now I want to do this by node.js code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have DB2 Express-C installed on your Mac (i.e. the server), then you already have the client libraries that you need.  When you go to build `ibm_db`, you can point the `IBM_DB_HOME` environment variable to the DB2 instance owner's `sqllib` directory.  For example:

```
export IBM_DB_HOME=/Users/db2inst1/sqllib
```

**NOTE:**  `ibm_db` will build and work, although the current release has an issue with the `bindings.gyp` file that prevent it from building on Mac OS X (it is configured to build ONLY on Linux).  You can add the following Condition to `bindings.gyp` to get it to build with `node-gyp`:

```
    [ 'OS == "mac" and target_arch =="x64" ', {
      'libraries' : [
        '-L$(IBM_DB_HOME)/lib -L$(IBM_DB_HOME)/lib64 ',
        '-ldb2'
      ],
      'include_dirs': [
        '$(IBM_DB_HOME)/include'
      ],
      'cflags' : [
        "-g "
      ],
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, but now I'm getting an 'Abort trap: 6' error.

Comment: I only want to connect to a remove DB. Is there a way to do this without creating a local database?

Comment: @Arkanoid Yes.  If you install the DB2 Client for Mac OS X you'll have largely the same steps as shown above – you'll still create an instance (a client instance, not a server instance).

Comment: @IanBjorhovde I couldn't find where to download it. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: When you go to download DB2 Express-C for Mac, you have an option to download the full server or just the client.