# Error DBI1189E installing DB2 on Mac Os X El Capitan

Tags: macos, installation, db2, osx-elcapitan

I have followed the instructions to install DB2 Express-C found [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797) (which is the official guide on the IBM community forum). Everything worked quite fine until I had to run the db2_install.
When I execute it, it gives me the DBI1189E error:

"DBI1189E There has been an attempt to use db2_install 
on an image for a platform that does not match the current platform 
'MacOS' on which it is being run.

Explanation:

Possible causes include:

- This DB2 install image is not valid for the current 
  platform.
- The current platform is not supported by DB2.

User Response:

Install DB2 using the DB2 install image that corresponds 
with the current platform 'MacOS'. "

Anyone knows what went wrong?

Comment: You can also create the ticket in IBM developerWorks in order to have a better answer. Leo Petraz https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last 2 days I also struggled with installing db2 on My Os X with the El Capitan.

First of all, important to know is that only version 10.1 is supported for mac, while for windows/linux, version 10.5 is supported.
This can cause troubles when migrating an existing database in 10.5 to your mac database in version 10.1. It is off course important to have the right distribution for mac os x.

I also tried the official guide on the IBM community forum, but it didn't work out for me too...

What I did was follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341171/how-do-i-install-db2-express-c-10-1-on-osx-mavericks) instructions.

With these instructions, the installation went find, but I encountered some issues with the line:

> 13. Initialize the sample database using this command:
>
>     db2sampl

Make sure you issue the db2start command using the db2inst1 user.

After my db was started I had [some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138859/cannot-db2start-using-db2-express-in-mac) with locked files.

I could solve them by issuing the command:

> sudo chown db2inst1 /Users/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/*

And then everything worked fine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! It all worked for the best up until step 11, but I stopped following the instructions because I had different ones given from my teacher specifically for our server, so I don't know about the other steps.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding references to seemingly the same problem for example [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014624177) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072871/how-do-i-install-ibm-db2-express-c-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion). All I am doing is googling for "DBI1189E mac os". Good luck and let me know if this has worked. Thanks!